# Edit Animated GIF to add polygons

Tags: gif

I am working on an animated gif with many layers and want to add a  polygon on all images. How to perform it ?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. What software are you using?  What have you tried? What has failed?  Please note that GDSE is not a tutorial request site.  There are tutorials on the internet for editing animated GIFs. Have you searched for any yet?

Comment: Adding to what @BillyKerr said... Can you also include an image of what you have and what you're trying to achieve? As it stands, this question is extremely vague and difficult to understand.

Comment: @WELZ  , BillyKerr , Thx. I have LightRoom and Photoshop, which I am not sure how to perform the change of adding a polygon to the Animated GIF, which have about 20 images. The Animates GIF works OK.